# Is there a clever way import my Mail.app rules to iCloud?

Tags: icloud, mail.app, mail-rules

I have a lot of rules in my Mail.app but when my computer is off my inbox fills up with junk and it's hard to read from the phone. I want to set up the rules on iCloud but don't see a way of uploading/importing them into iCloud. Am I missing something or do I need to set them up again manually?

Answer (score 2):

Try this. Go to iCloud.com and log in.

Select mail.

On the bottom left of the window, there is a cog:

[image]

Select that, and then Rules:

[image]

Finally, a window opens, and you can choose to sync Rules, or add specific rules just for iCloud.com (I think that's right.. not totally sure).

[image]

The help page is also useful.

[image]

Comment: I read through the Help manual for Cloud Mail. I don't see a facility to import mail rules, so probably, my answer isn't too helpful. I'll keep looking.

Comment: Further reading says you should be careful not to lose your desktop rules. Please see http://www.dafacto.com/2013/05/26/icloud-syncing-of-mail-rules/ There is a suggestion at the bottom on how to avoid this. (You may also want to make a copy of your ~/Library/Mail folder.)